# listbox with label count items in access and excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

In Excel I'm updating a label that counts the selected items of a listbox.
Everytime I deselect one the label counts one down.
I use this code:

Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer

```
With ListBox6
    For intIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(intIndex) Then intCount = intCount + 1
    Next
End With
Label1.Caption = "Deelnemers: " & intCount & " op " & ListBox6.ListCount
```

I'm trying to do the same in access, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question we might need extra information.
- Do you get an error message? 
- Where is label1 and listbox6? 
- What triggers the code? Which event do you (attempt to) use?

```
Dim intIndex As Integer 
Dim intCount As Integer = 0
With **Form1.**ListBox6
    For intIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(intIndex) Then 
              intCount += 1
        End if
    Next
    **Me.**Label1.Caption = "Deelnemers: " & intCount & " op " & .ListCount
End With
```

You could also try a for each loop;

```
Dim Li as listitem
dim seleciontcount as integer = 0
For each li in listbox6.items
    if li.selected then
         selectioncount += 1
    end if
next
```

Comment: The listbox and label1 are on a excel sheet. There it works fine.

Comment: But I'm Trying to make it work in an MS-Access form. There I have a list of competitors (query) and a label. Is this possible in MS-Access to?

Comment: I tried the loop but there I get an error concerning dim li as listitem.

Comment: The list of competitors is a combobox and when it opens al the competitors are selected. The label should count down everytime I deselect one.

Comment: You could try to dim li as var instead of listitem, but does the combobox have a multiselect property? I think you need to make your own combobox to make this work efficiëntly.

Add a panel or groupbox and fill this panel with labels for each of your items. Now you can easily count the amount of controls in the groupbox and add events to the labels to trigger code that makes another label show the amount of labels left.

Comment: dim li as var results in the same error. Is it possible that I need to set a reference? My label changes after update the combobox. The label should change everytime I change the list. Is it possible that this isn't available in access?